# how to find the length distance from rectangle in matlab?

Tags: matlab, shapes

This is the binary image of the rectangle :
http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=mog&hl=en&gl=us&client=ms-rim&tab=wi&q=rectangle%20binary&sa=N

I want to find the coordinate from left(xo) and the right(x1) to find the distance length and also the coordinate bottom(yo) and above(y1) to find width.
Where :
For length » Distance(X) = |X1-X0|
For width » Distance(Y) = |Y1-Y0|

Sincerely
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/images/art5.gif) input image you can simply do:

```
A = imread('art5.gif');
[y, x] = find(A==1);
my_length = max(x) - min(x) + 1
my_width = max(y) - min(y) + 1
```

This would give you:

```
my_length =

   171


my_width =

    89
```

Here since it is a logical gif, the above code would suffice. However, if the input image was in the RGB space, you would have needed:

```
A = im2bw(rgb2gray(imread('art5.gif')));
```

and if it was a grayscale image:

```
A = im2bw(imread('art5.gif'));
```

### EDIT

If you're using `'BoundingBox'` through the `regionprops()` function:

```
A = imread('art5.gif');
s = regionprops(A, 'BoundingBox');
my_length = s.BoundingBox(3)
my_width = s.BoundingBox(4)
```

This would give you:

```
my_length =

   171


my_width =

    89
```

Comment: But how if the rectangle in the boundingbox? Which I have selected it with regionprops, and then I want to find the ratio of Length(x1-x0)/ width(y1-y0) ?

Comment: @user1978112: Bounding box? Could you provide an example?

Comment: For example this image,http://www.google.com/search?q=binary+rectangle+bounding+box&hl=en&client=ms-rim&gl=us&tbm=isch&ei=36xeUYGtNcmwiQK-74CADA&start=20&sa=N . I have make the rectangle use regionprops('BoundingBox'). Now I want to find the ratio of the rectangle(BoundingBox).

Comment: @user1978112: I'm sorry, I'm not sure that I understand. Could you explain?

Comment: thanks a lot. That's working!! Well I want to make the ratio so I got. : my_ratio = my_length/my_width. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user1978112: Great! Please do accept and/or upvote the answer if it was what you were looking for.